# React - Redux - subscribe to external events

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-redux

I have a React-redux application, with stores, actions, reducers and all that stuff. All works as needed. 
But there is a small issue. BY clicking on a button I have to show an IFrame where another React application is loaded (very obsolete React). 
even here all works as needed.
What is doesn't work is catching the event that is triggered from the obsolete application.
to trigger the event I used such a code

```
window.parent.$(window.parent.document).trigger('HIDE_QUOTE_EDIT', {sender: 'quote-edit'});
```

I tried to subscribe to it in the main app as this

```
$(document).on('HIDE_QUOTE_EDIT', () => {console.log('Caught hide quote edit');});
```

but this never worked as needed.

1. What is best approach to handle such situation?
2. Say I catch this event somehow, how do I get the reference to the `dispatch` object so I can invoke an action?

Thx

P.S. I know this is not a correct design, but I have to work with whatever I have.

Comment: First figure out how to send events and receive them from iframes. That is a different question than best practices for handling external events in react/redux, so create another question for that. -1 from me, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use the jQuery from node, use the jQuery object from regular jQuery script in your html page, otherwise events won't be caught
2. in your mapDispatchToProp save the `dispatch` object as well, this you can access it via `this.props.dispatch` and dispatch any action you'd like

problem solved.